# Do I need to manage scope manually in angularjs in this case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I am (re)learning angularjs because I need to migrate some existing code to another framework.

I have a controller that is responsible for managing a saved favorites list rendered in a table. The favorites get saved to a mongodb collection. It looks like this:

```
export const favoritesController = ($scope, getFavorites, removeFavorites) => {
    getFavorites.then(favs => {
        $scope.favorites = favs;
    });

    // Called when a button is clicked
    // to remove selected favorites from a table.
    $scope.removeFavorite = ($event) => {
        let ids = [];
        $("#favorites input:checked").each((i, el) => {
            ids.push(parseInt(el.value));
        });
        removeFavorites(ids);

        // I know, we should ensure the
        // scope management occurs only 
        // when and if the
        // favs were successfully deleted. 
        $scope.favorites = $scope.favorites.filter(
            favorite => {
                return !ids.includes(favorite.id);
            });
   };
}
```

If I simply call the service to remove the favorites from the db (`removeFavorites`), the scope is unaffected and thus the favorites are not removed from their display table in the UI. I must also remove those favorites from the `$scope`. Is that correct? Is there some other way to connect the scope variable and the actions on the db, or am I correct that this must be done manually?

Comment: Yes you should manipulate the array manually, on html side you can access the $scope variables, and it is generally a good idea to keep it seperated from the service.

Comment: OK thanks. I thought maybe there was some trick or feature I was missing to somehow automatically sync the db with the scope.